# How to get data using jsonp?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jsonp

I'm trying to fetch some text from http://www.ikea.com/us/en/catalog/products/10176292 
using jsonp.

To test if it works this is what I did

```
$.getJSON("http://www.ikea.com/us/en/catalog/products/10176292?format=json&jsoncallback=?",function(data) {
$('h1').text(data.modified);
});
```

This doesn't work so it's probably no valid but all the jsonp documentation I've found on google use either twitter or flickr API as examples. I'm pretty sure IKEA doesn't have an API so those methods don't really help me.

However this does work and returns text from flickr

```
$.getJSON("http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?id=25053835@N03&format=json&jsoncallback=?",function(data) {
$('h1').text(data.title);
});
```

I'm attempting this because I saw this example http://www.foxycart.com/whos-using-foxy/case-studies/modernash and it appears to work with jsonp fetching text data from ikea. I don't need anything as complex, just to be able to retrieve some simple text.

Can someone please point me in the proper direction or give some tips.

Thanks

Comment: [That URL doesn't return JSON](http://www.ikea.com/us/en/catalog/products/10176292/?format=json&jsoncallback=foo), let alone JSONP. You can't just magically append some query parameters and expect to get back JSON(P); the server has to actually support it.

Comment: I tried it, the URL itself gives a `301 Moved Permanently` and redirects to a page of _HTML_ . It also doesn't send any [CORS headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) so you'd hit the [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript).

Comment: I kinda guessed it wouldn't work just like that, but I'm curious how do you guys think this developer managed to do it? I'm attempting this because I saw his example, where using his bookmark shopping cart he's able to pull data using JSONP from IKEA and use it 

http://www.foxycart.com/whos-using-foxy/case-studies/modernash

Comment: Actually, I found [the cross domain info](http://www.ikea.com/crossdomain.xml). Anyway, I can't see any requests to ikea itself. It looks like something happens server-side (probably curl, parse, return JSON) and the data is then fetched as normal.

Answer (score 0):

You can supplement your getJSON with ajax (see official docs here - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/), then it is super easy to declare JSONP.

```
    $.ajax({
      dataType: "jsonp",
      url: 'http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?id=25053835@N03&format=json&jsoncallback=?',
      data: data,
      success: function( data ) {
            $('h1').text(data.modified);
       });
```

Edit: @Matt Ball is right. Before you use something like the ajax call above you need to make sure that the URL that you are using is returning actual json. You should be able to navigate to the desired URL and see the raw JSON. Then all the above function will do is fetch and parse accordingly.

Comment: I know IKEA doesn't have an API, but I'm curious how did this developer do it? foxycart.com/whos-using-foxy/case-studies/modernash With his bookmark cart he's able to pull data off the IKEA site and send it off to the shopping cart. Isn't this against the same origin policy?

Comment: So after looking at your example site they specifically say "API. JSONP cart interaction. User syncing. Webhooks." Since IKEA doesn't appear to have an API and your URL isn't really JSON it looks like the folks at FoxyCart aren't using json and are probably using a custom webhook/script. So I guess to answer you're question you can't fetch JSON if there is no JSON to fetch. This dude (https://github.com/moritzh/ikea-data) wrote a gem to fetch stuff from IKEA, but its a bit more advanced than some simple jQuery. I would recommend doing some research on AJAX, REST, and basic http requests.

Answer (score 0):

The link to Ikea isn't JSON so you can't pull from it. It looks like Ikea doesn't have a public API. So, you won't be able to get any data from them to use.

For Flickr you are on the right track. Here is how you can do it.

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    url: 'http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?id=25053835@N03&format=json&jsoncallback=?',
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    } 
});
```

If you want to get the title you would do data.title and so on.

Comment: I know IKEA doesn't have an API, but I'm curious how did this developer do it? http://www.foxycart.com/whos-using-foxy/case-studies/modernash With his bookmark cart he's able to pull data off the IKEA site and send it off to the shopping cart. Isn't this against the same origin policy?

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like they are just scraping data from the site.  All the product information is stored in the html and they are adding that to an object into their own cart.

Since the you drag the image to their bookmarklet I looked at the data stored in the image @ http://www.ikea.com/us/en/catalog/products/20011408/#/80193735 :

```
<img id="productImg" src="/us/en/images/products/lack-side-table__0115088_PE268302_S4.JPG" border="0" alt="LACK Side table IKEA The high-gloss surfaces reflect light and give a vibrant look. Easy to assemble. Low weight; easy to move." title="LACK Side table - high gloss red, 21 5/8x21 5/8 &quot; - IKEA" width="500" height="500" class="mn_global_shadow ui-draggable" style="width: 244px; display: inline-block; height: 244px; left: 0px; top: 0px;">
```

In the title we get the name, finish, color, and size.
The price and quantity are held in id's/classes which seem standard across the entire site.

How it all works beyond that I haven't looked at, but it doesn't seem too complex.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to provide some custom headers. Wireshark is your friend